# How do I convert longLongValue to NSTimeInterval

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsnumber

I am getting a timestamp from server as longLongValue. I need to convert it to NSDate whose methods require NSTimeInterval. How do I do this correctly? The following resulted in some bizarre date

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[timestamp doubleValue]];
```

Comment: What is the result of an `NSLog`? What do you mean by "some bizarre date"?

Comment: OK `long long` does not describe what the value means, only how it's represented (i.e. 64-bit signed integer).  What do the values measures (i.e. what would `1` mean in this format)?

Comment: My input timestamp from server (java) is `1409211078761`. The iOS output is `Feb 14,46626, 1:52:41 AM`

Comment: You haven't answered the question.  What do the numbers mean?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are coming from Java, it means you are using System.currentTimeMillis  or something like that which uses millisecond time. But NSTimeInterval is always in seconds. So you should be using

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[timestamp longLongValue]/1000.0];
```

Comment: Where did you get the information that it's a Java server?  However this does look like the right answer :)

Comment: Confirmed from [here](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm).  Diving the number mentioned by the OP in the comments by 1000 gives `Thu, 28 Aug 2014 07:31:18 GMT` which looks good to me.

Comment: That's right, I also wrote a category to NSDate to perform the conversion from the java server timestamp to one of my projects

Comment: @trojanfoe the Java reference is in the conversation/comments.